# Velocity after inelastic collision between bullet and block

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, collision

The following is the problem that I am working on.

> A bullet of $.01\: \mathrm{kg}$ is shot into a block of mass $.89\: \mathrm{kg}$ that is hanging from the ceiling. After the bullet has been caught in the block, it swings and rises $.40\: \mathrm{m}$ from its initial height. Find the initial velocity of the bullet.

I though that $\frac{1}{2}m{v_0}^2 = (m+M)gh$ would give me the solution $25.6\: \mathrm{m/s}$, but the answer is supposedly $2.5 \times 10^2\: \mathrm{m/s}$. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are dealing with an inelastic collision, energy is not conserved when the bullet hits the block. You should try to find a relation between the initial velocity of the bullet and the velocity of the combined system (bullet+block) after the collision from **conservation of momentum**.

Comment: The problem is, assuming that the initial velocity is $v_0$ and the final velocity is $v_f$ of the embedded system, I get $mv_0=(m+M)v_f$ which then gives me $\frac{1}{2}(m+M){v_f}^2=\frac{1}{2}{mv_0}^2=(m+M)gh$ again, so that's the reason why I am asking if there is anything that I am missing out.

Comment: You know what, I had a miscalculation. It worked out perfectly. Thank you !